# 'Global' parent selector: limiting scope of any selector to a certain parent

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Im looking for an option to limit the scope of every selector to a parent selector.

Am trying to abstract away a lot of the (internal implementation) details of our WebApp for the testers that will actually write the UI tests.

If our application shows a Modal dialog (just a div tag that lies op top of all the other content and prevents interacting with the underlying content), I'd like to restrict all Selectors used in the tests written by testers to be automatically limited to the scope of this Modal Dialog div.

Our new client UI framework uses just divs for Modal Dialogs, while our previous client UI framework used an embedded iframe for each modal dialog. In the iframe scenario, we'd call .switchToIframe(), which would effectively limited all selectors used in tests to this iframe.

Am trying to achieve something similar for the new client framework that uses just divs

Comment: It seems difficult to manually restrict access to the DOM beyond a specific point because every DOM element has the `Node.parentNode` and `Node.parentElement` links. So, I can confirm that the [Page Object Model](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402826/guides/concepts/page-model) is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can limit the scope of the DOM like that, but you could build out a Page Object Model (POM) design that would only intelliSense existing locators from their respected repos. This way, if they begin typing a locator and it doesn't pop up, a hint that they aren't in the 'scope' of the modal.